# How can I compare the values in one column to the values in other columns?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I have a spreadsheet where people go on and rank songs (each song has its own row and each user has their own column), how can I write a script to iterate over each user column and then compare the individual user's rating of each song to the column that is the input?

The goal is to output the column with rankings most similar to the input column's rankings (ideally this should be an iterative recursive function with space complexity of `O(1)` and time complexity of `O(log(n))`.

I would think to make a function that produces a formula to be used like `=FINDMOSTSIMILAR(<USER>)` that outputs the value of the first row in the output column, but I'm not sure where to begin.  I have some experience in JavaScript and I know Google Apps Script is based on JS, but I don't know how to do this function in GAS.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ruDFa8jmC3okuMvE6n6XfHMU66dNYEfxgUdXl-CMzJo/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to give you a start. Go to sheet, click **Tools > Script Editor**. Paste this code.

To find similar user, what this code does is, between input user and any other user, calculate differences for every song ratings and add them to produce a value. Do this for every user in sheet. Then find the lowest of differences and output which user produces this value. This logic is separated in `compare` function and you can change it to suit your needs.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Find Similar User')
      .addItem('Similar User', 'showPrompt')
      .addToUi();
}

// this configuration is based on current sheet names and formatting
// if sheet names change, change needed here
// if track title and user columns change, change needed here
var config = {
  // sheet name: [ col of track title, col of 1st user, col of last user ]
  "UV6": [6, 9, 28],
  "Midnight Underground": [7, 11, 28],
  "Furious Fap February": [8, 12, 23],
  "March Masturbation Madness": [7, 11, 31]
};

function showPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.prompt(
    'Find similar user.',
      'Enter user name:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    text = text.trim();
    if (!text) return;
    FINDMOSTSIMILAR(text);
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {

  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {

  }
}

function FINDMOSTSIMILAR(username) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var aSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var aSheetName = aSheet.getName();

  // get positions from config
  if (!config[aSheetName]) return;
  var userNamesColsStart = config[aSheetName][1];
  var userNamesColsSpan = config[aSheetName][2] - config[aSheetName][1] + 1;
  var titleColStart = config[aSheetName][0];

  // read user names
  var users = aSheet.getRange(1,userNamesColsStart,1,userNamesColsSpan).getValues()[0];
//  Logger.log(users);

  // read title col
  var tArr = aSheet.getRange(2,titleColStart,aSheet.getLastRow()-2,1).getValues();
//  Logger.log(tArr);

  // data structure
  var DS = {};
  users.forEach(function(h, i) {
    var obj = {};
    var colValues = aSheet.getRange(2,userNamesColsStart+i,aSheet.getLastRow()-2,1).getValues();
    tArr.forEach(function(v, i) {
      obj[i] = colValues[i][0];
    });
    DS[h] = obj;
  });
//  Logger.log(DS);

  var target = DS[username];
  delete DS[username];

  var results = [];

  Object.keys(DS).forEach(function(user) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.prop = username+'__'+user;
    obj.value = compare(target, DS[user]);
    results.push(obj);
  });

  // sort based on difference values
  results.sort(comp);
  Logger.log(results);

  // user with lowest difference is answer
  var similarUser = results[0].prop.split('__')[1];
  Logger.log(similarUser);

  try {
    ss.getActiveCell().setValue([similarUser]);
  } catch(e) {}

}

function comp(a, b) {
  if (a.value < b.value) return -1;
  else if (a.value > b.value) return 1;
  else return 0;
}

// this takes a difference of two users ratings for the same song
// accumulate all the differences for all songs into a single value
// change here how to compare 2 song ratings
function compare(target, user) {
  var v = 0;
  Object.keys(target).forEach(function(key, i) {
    v += Math.abs(target[key] - user[key]);
  });
  return v;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, running the code gave me an error: `TypeError: Expected an argument of type object, but instead had type undefined (line 61, file 'Code')`.  I tried to run `FINDMOSTSIMILAR` on it's own

Comment: Inside script editor, change `FINDMOSTSIMILAR('corbin');` line to put different user names to test. Then go to **Run > Run Function > test**. How did you test it ?

Comment: I clicked on the drop-down with the names of functions, selected `test`, and clicked the run icon.  What i'm trying to do is make it so that I can input in a cell in sheets the following: `=FINDMOSTSIMILAR(<username>)` to the result of the output in that cell.

Comment: Edited code. Copy, paste and save. Reload sheet tab. Will open a Custom Menu at the right end of menu bar, click Similar User, enter user name, see 'output' sheet.

Comment: that should work, I'll tinker with it a bit to suit my needs, but thanks a ton!

Comment: how can I convert it to the following spreadsheet? 
 I really need it to work as a formula in the spreadsheet rather than a custom function.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jDdH0Uec-S6qE4DMOCAWncO9WJ9apsFC6CURPIScv2M/edit#gid=177381259

Comment: When I run it on the spreadsheet, it just returns the leftmost value, not the actual value.  Code: https://script.google.com/d/MBzzATYo9vzk_59r-BUZLAwlqiUOunoQW/edit?mid=ACjPJvFb0u8h87CqmpX-ThC9J2BaysQWdDQAS41mrV__1pU0ffwvcnc48-cdiMh1rk_T-fHyPDTWVPUgxLPbJYjkxvRR4W6Yo7u5xLxh2MRqtY19r0_sQSkdN9eLkShouH07az4wYQTXBO0&uiv=2

Comment: Your sheets have different configurations as to where are track titles and user columns. Added a config object based on that and edited code to use new config. Try new code.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  How should I do this?

Comment: Copy this code and paste as before. Save and reload sheet. I covered existing 4 sheets in config in code. That should cover now. Try testing as before.

Comment: Now it just returns the title of the column farthest to the left...  Any ideas why?

Comment: You changed code into this `try {
    ss.getActiveCell();
  } catch(e) {}
  ss.getActiveCell().setValue([similarUser]);` it'll write to A1 cell by default if you hadn't activated another cell by clicking. Click on another cell in sheet and try. User name will be printed into that active cell.

Comment: I did that because inserting a new sheet for results doesn't work for the rest of the people on this sheet

Comment: That is okay but you should know what code you're writing and what will be the result. Blindly trying anything doesn't work in case of coding I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes I wish I knew sheets better.  I'm trying to learn it but for now I might have to blindly try things.  Also no matter what I do it still returns the farthest left cell

Comment: Just clicking on a tab name below does activate the sheet and A1 cell by default. Click on a cell in the row you have reserved for similar user after you go to a sheet. I am testing and it works everytime. Come to this sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nGFewGIF_EWlsszr74cHGXCfUzpYNuy6KVe89W7Nz78/edit?usp=sharing